# What is a good alternative to using an empty abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract

Suppose I have the following:

```
public abstract class AbstractResponse {
  // this class is totally empty!
}

public class ResponseA extends AbstractResponse {
  // JSON POJO 
}

public class ResponseB extends AbstractResponse {
  // JSON POJO 
}

public abstract class AbstractClient {
  public abstract Class getType();

  public AbstractResponse readResponse() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    AbstractResponse response;
    try {
        return (AbstractResponse) mapper.readValue(data, getType());
    } catch (IOException e) {...}
  }
}

public class ResponseAClient extends AbstractClient {
  public Class getType() {
    return ResponseA.class;
  }
}

public class ResponseBClient extends AbstractClient {
  public Class getType() {
    return ResponseB.class;
  }
}
```

`ResponseA` and `ResponseB` have nothing in common besides being a JSON POJO. As you can see I am using an empty abstract class `AbstractResponse` to avoid duplicated code for `readResponse()` in the client classes `ResponseAClient` and `ResponseBClient`.

**My question**:

Is it bad practice to use an empty abstract class for similar cases and if so, what would be the best way to code this? I have thought about using generics but I've seen many warnings that discourage the use of Java Generics.

**Edit:** Thanks for the quick response guys. After the useful comments from @Kayaman I'd like to rephrase my question like this:

Is there a better implementation for the kind of situation I've described above than using an empty interface/abstract class. It just seems like bad practice to have an empty interface/abstract class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use an interface. There's no sense in using an empty abstract class (unless you want to prevent the classes from subclassing another class).

As for your "many warnings that discourage the use of Java Generics.", I'd be happy to see some links, because that's just not true.

Edit: A generic approach could give you something like the following (`Response` is an empty interface for marking concrete response classes and limiting the allowed types that `Client` can handle)

```
public class Client<T extends Response> {
    private Class<T> clazz;
    public Client(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
    public T readResponse() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        return (T) mapper.readValue(data, clazz);
    }
}
```

Allowing you to handle responses that are strongly typed.

```
Client<ResponseA> clientA = new Client<>(ResponseA.class);
ResponseA resp = clientA.readResponse();
```

So the answer to the question "What's a good alternative to an empty abstract class" is "Refactor and Redesign".

Comment: I knew what the answer would be before even opening the question :-)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Why is using an empty interface better than using an empty abstract class?

Comment: @Diyarbakir That's such a basic question that I suggest you look it up yourself (what's the difference between an interface and abstract class).

Comment: @Kayaman Sorry, let me rephrase it like this: Is there a better implementation for the kind of situation I've described above then using an empty interface/abstract class. It just seems like bad practice to have an empty interface/abstract class.

Comment: @Diyarbakir That's a better question.

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you for this clear answer. It will help me a lot. I'll indeed "Refactor and Redesign" :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an empty interface or abstract class, I'd rather use an annotation with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`. That is a little more code to write though, and may not be especially readable and fast (the part where you want to check if a class has this annotation).

There are empty interfaces in the language, like `Serializable`. But since Java 5 it doesn't make too much sense anymore.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

public abstract class AbstractClient {
    public abstract Class getType();

    public Object readResponse() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            Object response = mapper.readValue(data, getType());

            if (response.getClass().getDeclaredAnnotation(Response.class) == null) {
                // Not a valid type
            }

            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {...}
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@interface Response {

}

@Response
class ResponseA extends AbstractResponse {
    // JSON POJO
}

@Response
class ResponseB extends AbstractResponse {
    // JSON POJO
}


class ResponseAClient extends AbstractClient {
    public Class getType() {
        return ResponseA.class;
    }
}

class ResponseBClient extends AbstractClient {
    public Class getType() {
        return ResponseB.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Marker interfaces still make sense. I'd prefer a method `void dooFoobar(MarkerInterface object)`, where `MarkerInterface` is an empty interface over `void dooFoobar(Object o)` where o has to be annotated. The first option gives you more type safety at compile time.

Comment: While empty interfaces aren't exactly the best way to go, they still have some use (especially if the alternative is an empty abstract class). As Alex showed in his comment and I did in my answer, it can be a good way to provide additional type safety or limit things (such as parameters or generics).

Comment: @Alex I am not sure type safety applies here. Knowing that this object implements an empty interface doesn't help you more than knowing that it extends `Object`. If you need to access its members, you will still need some casting or reflection. But I agree it is easier to write.

Comment: With type safety I mean you can do:
`MarkerInterface mi = getMI(); dooFoobar(mi);` - of course you are responsible for only implementing `MarkerInterface` when it is necessary/okay. But using this approach, you can't do `dooFoobar(new String("doesnt compile"));`, which would be okay at compile time if I used annotations.

Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying annotations would be totally wrong here, I just think a marker interface would be slightly better here.